# Apache says it runs on Unix, but doesn't say the distro

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, arch-linux

I've Apache installed in my Parabola GNU/Linux-libre SBC (Arch/ALARM based) and it's everything OK, except for a little detail. When I see a directory with files, or go to a page that doesn't exists, you can always see info about Apache at the bottom of the website, with something like:

> Apache/2.4.27 (Distro Name) OpenSSL/1.1.0f

But in my case it says:

> Apache/2.4.27 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.0f PHP/7.1.8

And it says "Unix" instead of the distro's name. IDK why this happens, all the Apache packages for ARM come from ALARM, but anyways this is quite strange. How do I fix this? Thnx

Comment: as an aside, you should probably disable that footer entirely, as it's a security issue. http://ask.xmodulo.com/turn-off-server-signature-apache-web-server.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally got it. I just had to enable [mod_security](http://www.queryadmin.com/206/change-apache-server-signature-mod_security/) (see [this](http://idiallo.com/blog/changing-apache-server-signature) also) by installing it [from the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/modsecurity/).

This is what I putted at the end of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
# Apache signature change
ServerTokens Full
LoadFile /usr/lib/libxml2.so
LoadFile /usr/lib/liblua5.1.so
LoadModule security2_module modules/mod_security2.so
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
SecServerSignature "Apache (Parabola GNU/Linux-libre)"
</IfModule>
```

You also need to have the libxml2 and the lua51 packages installed.